# Is there a way to make keras custom test_step aware of the call being made from model.fit and model.evaluate

Tags: keras, tensorflow, machine-learning-model

I am using keras custom model with custom train_step and test_step methods overwritten. Also, have a need to change certain margin used in the loss function, only for test dataset. In other words I want to use one value of margin for training and validation datasets, but a little relaxed margin for test datasets. I think I can accomplish this if the test_step method gets to know(some how) if the function call has come from model.fit(validation part) and model.evaluate(test part).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can do that. You can just use a flag or variable that you can set based on the context in which the method is being called and in this way you can make the custom **test_step** method aware of the call being made from **model.fit** and **model.evaluate**.

Well, what you can do is that you could define a variable **is_training** in your custom model, and set it to **True** in the **train_step** method and to **False** in the **test_step** method. Then, you can use this variable to determine whether the model is being trained or evaluated in the **test_step** method.

Comment: I think, I didn't get it entirely. How setting is_training **inside** train_step or test_step helps this condition! I am guessing such kind of setting has to be done outside of test_step, that way test_step would know where the call has come from. My apologies, if I didn't get it correctly, can you rephrase it please.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice `keras.backend.in_train_phase()` function for that. It is not documented (intentionally) but its signature is:

```
def in_train_phase(
    x: Any,
    alt: Any,
    training: Any | None = None
) -> Any
```

`Selects x in train phase, and alt otherwise.`